# Python Rock Paper Scissors error

Tags: python

I get this error about x not being defined when trying to run this. I am new to python. Any help would be appreciated. Also any way to make this more clean code would be great.

https://pastebin.com/Kgw3gNsV

```
import random

choices = ["rock", 'paper', 'scissors']

def playainput():
    playachoice = ("")
    playerinput = input("Input rock, paper, or scissors:  ")

    if playerinput == ("rock"):
                playachoice += ("you chose rock")
    elif playerinput == ("paper"):
                playachoice += ("you chose paper")
    elif playerinput == ("scissors"):
                playachoice += ("You chose scissors")
    else:
        print ("oops type again")
        playainput()

    print (playachoice)


def choose(x):
    choice = random.choice(x)
    print ("I chose %s" %choice)

x = playachoice
y = choose(choices)

if x == ("rock") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("you win")
if x == ("rock") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("you lose!")
if x == ("rock") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("tie")

if x == ("paper") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("I win!")
if x == ("paper") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("tie!")
if x == ("paper") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("you win!")

if x == ("scissors") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("tie!")
if x == ("scissors") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("you win!")
if x == ("scissors") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("you lose!")
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, verbatim directly in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Side-note: All those random parens surrounding `str` literals are pointless, and just make the code more confusing (they have zero effect on behavior). Why do you think you need them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `playachoice` is local to the function `playainput()`.  So at the end of `playainput()` add:

```
return playerinput
```

And then change x assignment to:

```
x = playainput()
```

**Update:**

You had several small errors  Let's try:

```
import random

choices = ["rock", 'paper', 'scissors']

def playainput():
    while True:
        playerinput = input("Input rock, paper, or scissors:  ")
        if playerinput in choices:
            print("You chose", playerinput)
            break

        print ("oops type again")
    return playerinput

def choose(x):
    choice = random.choice(x)
    print ("I chose %s" % choice)
    return choice

x = playainput()
y = choose(choices)

outcomes = {
    ("rock", "rock"): "tie!",
    ("rock", "paper"): "you lose",
    ("rock", "scissors"): "you win",
    ("paper", "rock"): "you win",
    ("paper", "paper"): "tie!",
    ("paper", "scissors"): "you lose",
    ("scissors", "rock"): "you lose",
    ("scissors", "paper"): "you win",
    ("scissors", "scissors"): "tie!",
}
print(outcomes[x, y])
```

Comment: This works! thank you for helping out a python new guy.

Answer (score 0):

First the variable `playachoice` is local and not global which means you can only access in from within the `playainput()`. So you will have to return the variable from the `playainput()` before you can assign `x = playainput()`.

Second, why are you trying to assign `playachoice` to x? That variable will contain `"you chose rock"` and so on. I think you need to return `playerinput` so that your comparisons down below makes sense. So add `print playachoice` and `return playerinput` to the end of `playainput()`

Third, you don't have to initialise `playachoice` to an empty string and then add strings below in the if-else clause. I think you should be able directly assign the "you chose rock" etc to playachoice.

Forth, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input()`can only be used if you want to input integers, floats etc.

Fifth, you should also return `choice` from `choose(x)`

I think this should work

```
import random

choices = ["rock", 'paper', 'scissors']


def playainput():

    playerinput = raw_input("Input rock, paper, or scissors:  ")

    if playerinput == ("rock"):
                playachoice = ("you chose rock")
    elif playerinput == ("paper"):
                playachoice = ("you chose paper")
    elif playerinput == ("scissors"):
                playachoice = ("You chose scissors")
    else:
        print ("oops type again")
        playainput()

    return playerinput



def choose(x):
    choice = random.choice(x)
    print ("I chose %s" %choice)
    return choice

x = playainput()
y = choose(choices)

if x == ("rock") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("you win")
if x == ("rock") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("you lose!")
if x == ("rock") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("tie")

if x == ("paper") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("I win!")
if x == ("paper") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("tie!")
if x == ("paper") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("you win!")

if x == ("scissors") and y == ("scissors"):
    print ("tie!")
if x == ("scissors") and y == ("paper"):
    print ("you win!")
if x == ("scissors") and y == ("rock"):
    print ("you lose!")
```